# Why does tensor output for WAV file from tensorflow's AudioIOTensor differ from output of decode_wav?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, audio

I'm trying to modify the datapipe line from a Kaggle notebook at [Kaggle Notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/huntingdata11/z-by-hp-unlocked-challenge-3-tutorial), so that it can work audio files other than WAV (specifically, I'm modifying it to work on some mp3 files I have). The data I'm testing with (initially) comes from [Kaggle Data](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/kenjee/z-by-hp-unlocked-challenge-3-signal-processing)

This notebook reads the WAV file into a tensor using this method:

```
def decode_audio(audio_binary):
    # Decode WAV-encoded audio files to `float32` tensors, normalized
    # to the [-1.0, 1.0] range. Return `float32` audio and a sample rate.
    audio, _ = tf.audio.decode_wav(contents=audio_binary,desired_channels=1,)

    # Since all the data is single channel (mono), drop the `channels`
    # axis from the array.
    return tf.squeeze(audio, axis=-1)
```

I have (slightly) modified it , so that it will work directly from the file name like this:

```
def decode_audio1(filename):
    # Decode WAV-encoded audio files to `float32` tensors, normalized
    # to the [-1.0, 1.0] range. Return `float32` audio and a sample rate.
    audio_binary = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    audio, _ = tf.audio.decode_wav(contents=audio_binary,desired_channels=1,)

    # Since all the data is single channel (mono), drop the `channels`
    # axis from the array.
    return tf.squeeze(audio, axis=-1)
```

However, since I want to use non-WAV files (i.e. mp3), I needed to replace the decode_wav method. I did this:

```
 def decode_audio2(filename):
    # Load audio file
    file_contents = tfio.audio.AudioIOTensor(filename, dtype=tf.float32)
        
    # Since all the data is single channel (mono), drop the `channels`
    # axis from the array.
    audio = file_contents.to_tensor()[:,0]

    # AudioIOTensor creates int16 tensor instead of float32 and
    # is larger than decode_wav's output by factor of 2**15
    audio = tf.cast(audio,tf.float32)/32768
    
    return audio
```

The data label is determined by the directory in which the file is stored:

```
def get_label(file_path):
    parts = tf.strings.split(
        input=file_path,
        sep=os.path.sep)
    # Note: You'll use indexing here instead of tuple unpacking to enable this
    # to work in a TensorFlow graph.
    return parts[-2]
```

The first part of the pipeline calls the decode_audio and get_label methods to return a waveform and label like this:

```
def get_waveform_and_label1(file_path):
    label = get_label(file_path)
    # Original code to get decoded audio
    #audio_binary = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    #waveform = decode_audio(audio_binary)
    
    # Minor change to use method that decodes given file path
    waveform = decode_audio1(file_path)

    return waveform, label
```

I also created a slightly modified version of this method that uses *my* decode_audio method:

```
def get_waveform_and_label2(file_path):
    label = get_label(file_path)
    waveform2 = decode_audio2(file_path)

    return waveform2, label
```

Now, using the approach from the source notebook, I can begin to gather a dataset:

```
# Set the seed value for experiment reproducibility.
seed = 1842
tf.random.set_seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)

#data_dir = "/kaggle/input/z-by-hp-unlocked-challenge-3-signal-processing"
data_dir = './KaggleBirdCallData'
commands = ["Parsed_Capuchinbird_Clips","Parsed_Not_Capuchinbird_Clips"]
filenames_Capuchinbird = tf.io.gfile.glob(str(data_dir) + '/Parsed_Capuchinbird_Clips/*')
filenames_Not_Capuchinbird = tf.io.gfile.glob(str(data_dir) + '/Parsed_Not_Capuchinbird_Clips/*')
filenames =tf.concat([filenames_Capuchinbird, filenames_Not_Capuchinbird], 0)
filenames = tf.random.shuffle(filenames)
num_samples = len(filenames)
print('Number of total examples:', num_samples)

train_split = int(.8*num_samples)

train_files = filenames[:train_split]

print('Training set size', len(train_files))
```

I had thought my variation on the decode_audio function is OK, because it seems to return the same value as the original:

```
>>test_file = b'./KaggleBirdCallData/Parsed_Capuchinbird_Clips/XC216012-2.wav'
>>t1 = decode_audio1(test_file)
>>t2 = decode_audio2(test_file)
>>t1,t2
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(168000,), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([-0.04940796, -0.05596924, -0.06036377, ..., -0.05697632,
         0.01339722,  0.07778931], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(168000,), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([-0.04940796, -0.05596924, -0.06036377, ..., -0.05697632,
         0.01339722,  0.07778931], dtype=float32)>,

>>(t1-t2).numpy().any()
False
```

So, I next went and created the first part of the data pipeline:

```
files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_files)
# Uses original method - decode_wav
waveform_ds1 = files_ds.map(
    map_func=get_waveform_and_label1,
    num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    
# Uses my method with AudioIOTensor
waveform_ds2 = files_ds.map(
    map_func=get_waveform_and_label2,
    num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

However, when I try to use my method in the notebook, I invariably get various crashes. The earliest I am able to induce one is by looping through waveform_ds. For example, when I try this using the original approach with `decode_wav`:

```
for i, (audio, label) in enumerate(waveform_ds1.take(2)):
    print(i)
```

I get:

```
0
1
```

which is expected.

When I try:

```
for i, (audio, label) in enumerate(waveform_ds2.take(2)):
    print(i)
```

I get this error message & crash:

```
2023-12-08 11:35:05.364557: F tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.cc:770] Check failed: dtype() == expected_dtype (1 vs. 5) int16 expected, got float
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Now, because AudioIO tensor returns an `int16` tensor, instead of the `float32` from decode_wav, I tried this variation on my decode function:

```
def decode_audio3(filename):
    # Load audio file
    file_contents = tfio.audio.AudioIOTensor(filename, dtype=tf.float32)
    
    # Removes trailing axis
    audio = file_contents.to_tensor()[:,0]

    return audio
```

But got the same error and crash. Am I using AudioIOTensor incorrectly? What am I not understanding? Why do the decode methods produce the same (as far as I can tell) output, yet only one of them can function within a data pipeline?